# HTML selected option not changing when user chooses different option

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm having some issues with a dropdown I created with HTML. The options that populate the select dropdown come from my database. I want the user to be able to choose a place type (job, school, work etc.) from the dropdown, once selected the user can click on the map to drop a point or type in the address. 
The input for the address is disabled until the user selects something from the dropdown. My problem is that the selected dropdown option does not reflect the change to the user. It's just stuck on the job option, but when you click on the map the point and the correct label title is placed.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aTRRdNb.png]

HTML:

```
<select name="places" id="places" class="form-control" onchange="addPlace(this)">
        <option value="" selected disabled="">Choose one</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addPlace() {

    places = document.getElementById("places");
    place = places.options[places.selectedIndex].textContent;

    if (place.value === "") {
        alert("Alert Message");
        document.getElementById("address").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("address").disabled = false;
    }

    if (place !== "") {
        placeTogo.push(place);
        if (map1 === undefined) {
            loadAPI();
        }
    } else if (place == "Other") {
        placeId = places.selectedIndex + 1;

    } else {
        placeId = places.selectedIndex + 1;
        placeTogo.push(place);

        if (map1 === undefined) {
            loadAPI();
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        places[i].selected = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more code? to replicate the form on your picture. We don't need the map or any of that just the form....it'd be easier to help you out. :)

Comment: I don't see any jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(It's a little difficult to ascertain how exactly this code fits into your application (and whether or not it will run as intended), but here's my best crack at solving the specific problems you mentioned above*

> My problem is that the selected dropdown option does not reflect the change to the user. It's just stuck on the job option, but when you click on the map the point and the correct label title is placed.

1. The for-loop at the end of your `addPlace` function is causing this behavior; it is deselecting *every* option the moment your selection changes, and the browser doesn't know what to do other than pick the first non-disabled option ("Job"). The browser already does the work of updating the selected state of each option for you; just delete that for-loop entirely.
2. Instead of using `textContent` to determine which option is selected, use the `value` property (then you can change the visible text later without having to worry about your JS code breaking).
3. Disable your `input#address` with an HTML attribute, because the change event won't be fired on change load (and thus your address would otherwise be editable by default).
4. There are a few sections of your change handler that don't seem necessary, but since I don't have the whole context of your project at hand I hesitate to adjust much else. For example, your alert will never run, because the only option with an empty string value is disabled (despite being initially selected).

```js
/* Here are all of the things I guessed about
your implementation to get this example to work */

var placeTogo = [], // `push` made me guess this is an array
    map1 = {} // some object loaded by the api?
function loadAPI() {
    console.log('Tried to load API')
}

/* Here's where your original code begins, with edits */

function addPlace() {

    places = document.getElementById("places");
    place = places.options[places.selectedIndex].value;

    if (!place) {
        alert("Alert Message");
        document.getElementById("address").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("address").disabled = false;
    }

    if (place) {
        placeTogo.push(place);
        if (map1 === undefined) {
            loadAPI();
        }
    } else if (place == "Other") {
        placeId = places.selectedIndex + 1;

    } else {
        placeId = places.selectedIndex + 1;
        placeTogo.push(place);

        if (map1 === undefined) {
            loadAPI();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<select name="places" id="places" class="form-control" onchange="addPlace(this)">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose one</option>
    <option value="Jobs">Jobs</option>
    <option value="Work">Work</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<input id="address" disabled placeholder="123 Main Street"/>
```

Comment: The code is a bit complicated, I'm trying to redesign and refactor this application. but your solution worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad it helped. If you'd like some refactoring suggestions, you might want to post this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) as well.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I think in HTML option tag it's just 'disabled' , not disabled="".